# Ignoring certain files when pushing an existing repo to a new Github repo

Tags: git, github

After creating a new Github repository using the Github website, I wanted to push my existing project to that repository.

However, I don't want to push **large** files whose extensions are **.mat**, **.npy**, or **.csv**.

Github suggests the following two commands for pushing an existing repository from the command line:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/project_name.git
git push -u origin master
```

But, is it possible to have the push command ignore certain files or extensions ?

Setting up `.gitignore` didn't seem to help, I believe that document is for ignoring files when creating commits but not for initially pushing the local repo to the online repo.

Comment: Have you committed ignored files already? If so then you need to delete them and commit your changes. Then you can push your project.

Comment: If you've already got those files commited, but don't want them commited, see the article on [removing files added in older commits](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/#removing-a-file-added-in-an-older-commit).  They recommend a tool called [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) but it's probably possible to do it with just `git filter-branch` (though BFG may be easier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the large files from the history of your local repository using the `filter-branch` command. See the steps in the filter-branch section of this [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/).

The files will be kept in your local working tree, but the history of your repository will be rewritten, which means the commit ids will change after the first commit that added such files.

In addition, to prevent committing those files by accident, I suggest to create `.gitignore` appropriately.